# Array reduce filter not working with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, jquery-ui-slider

I'm writing a code where there are sliders, when the sliders values change, I want to make an api call and get the result. Here is my code.

```
function alertValues() {
    var alcohol, sulphate, sulphur;
    //Or
    if ($("#sliderValueAlcohol").val()) {
        alcohol = $("#sliderValueAlcohol").val();
    }
    if ($("#sliderValueSulphate").val()) {
        sulphate = $("#sliderValueSulphate").val();
    }
    if ($("#sliderValueSulphur").val()) {
        sulphur = $("#sliderValueSulphur").val();
    }
    if (alcohol && sulphate) {
        var idString = sulphate + "";
        var id = 1;

        console.log(typeof id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'https://thcj3oq32b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/getsimulation',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "targetState": "7"
            }),
            /* etc */
            success: function (jsondata) {
                var arr2 = jsondata;
                var result = arr2
                    .filter(function (objs) {
                        return ((objs.find((obj) => obj.ingredients === "sulphate").min <= id) && (objs.find((obj) => obj.ingredients === "sulphate").max >= id) && (objs.find((obj) => obj.ingredients === "alcohol").max == 14));
                    })
                    .reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return a.concat(b);
                    });

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].target_state));

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        })
    }
}
```

here when I pass `var id = parseFloat(idString);`, instead of static number, the error that I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value`. unable to understand where am I going wrong. please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, could you put a console.log on the jsonData in the success function and also console.log the id before ajax call and show what the values are?

Comment: Why not just give an initial value to the reduce function, eg: `.reduce(function(a, b) { ... }, [])`?

Comment: @CRice, this is returning me a blank array :(

Comment: Yes, this is because the array you are reducing is empty to begin with. Are you expecting that the `result.filter( ... )` call will never give you an empty array?

Comment: @CRice, sorry, I didn't get you. Here is a working piece with static number, Can you please update it with your thought. https://jsfiddle.net/vjt45xv4/20/

Comment: What @CRice is saying is that your `filter()` function is returning an empty array. When you use `reduce()` on an empty array without a default value you get that error. Try looking ar what `filter()` is retuning before trying `reduce()`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the value in the reduce operation. Add the empty array initial value []

Comment: this is returning me a blank array :(

Comment: I see it working in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vjt45xv4/20. The array does not look empty

Comment: yes it is, if I pass a static value, but it doesn't when I pass in my slider value :(